# AWS Next.js on EC2 caching

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, next.js, amazon-cloudfront

I'm planning to use **Next.js** SSR/SSG/ISR on Amazon's **EC2** and store images on **S3 Bucket**. Also to add **CloudFront** CDN on top of it.

**The question is:**
Should I cache images from S3 in Next.js (which is in EC2) thus "doubling" images (origin in S3, optimised instances in EC2 Next.js cache), or it makes no sense, since everything is located within one cloud (AWS) and covered with CDN layer (CloudFront)?
Or there is a way to move next.js caching to CloudFront?

I do understand that `next/image` is providing image optimisation (different sizes and quality), but I'm bothered by "doubling" the images, thus paying more for storage.

P.S. I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62105756/how-to-use-aws-with-next-js), I'm just not experienced with lambda, so currently looking for something I understand already.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudfront gives you the option to have different origin for different behaviours and you can also apply different cache policy per behaviour. What you can do is have a behaviour for /images which will go to S3 and Default behaviour will point to  Ec2 origin.